# How to implement mobile version of SPA at ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I need to implement a mobile version of my App on ReactJS. I want to make a variable that will take the width of the screen and then depends on this variable render Mobile Components or Desktop Components. Is it OK or are there other solutions?

Comment: You can make the website responsive instead, but yeah, just set state according to `window.innerWidth` when the app mounts, then render conditionally. (also note that broad "how to" questions are likely to get downvoted; you might want to do more research and try stuff, then edit/post the question when you're stuck)

Comment: I can make it responsive, but in mobile version logic of my app totally different